What jaati would you classify Ektaal under?
Daadra taal is tisra-jaati (3/3), Teentaal is chatusra-jaati (4/4/4/4), Jhaptaal is khanda-jaati(2/3/2/3), Rupak is mishra-jaati (3/4). In the modern interpretation, Ektaal is segmented as 2/2/2/2/2/2, so I am not sure what jaati to place it in. In theory, would we call a two-beat pattern a variation of the four-beat chatusra-jaati?
Along the same lines, if it is true that Ektaal was originally 6/6 with taali on 1st and khali on 7th, then I suppose it could be a variation of tisra-jaati? While I don't know for sure whether the 6/6 theory for Ektaal is true, I do like it, as Ektaal has a lovely symmetry when divided that way.
dhin dhin dhaage tirakita tun  naa
kat  taa  dhaage tirakita dhin naa
To add some information, when we talk of rhythm, tisra jaati means "three beat pattern," chatusra jaati means four-beat pattern, khanda jaati refers to 5-beat patterns that are split into 2+3, mishra jaati refers to a 7-beat pattern, which is a combination of 3+4. There is additionally a sankirna jaati, which refers to a 4+2+3 (=9) pattern. The origin of taal classification under different jaati (=types) goes back over 2000 years and has evolved subsequently. But the traditional types are 3-beat patterns, 4-beat patterns, 5-beat patterns (2+3), 7-beat patterns (3+4), and 9-beat patterns (4+5 = 4+2+3). 6-beat patterns are simply twice 3-beat patterns, and 8-beat patters are simply twice the 4-beat patterns.
My question is, therefore, two-fold. 
(1) How is a 2-beat pattern customarily classified - would it be a khanda jaati (khanda means split, and 2 is half of a 4-beat pattern)? 
(2) What is the evolution of Ektaal, and does that give us any insights into how it may originally have been split, which would give us some insights into what the jaati of Ektaal would originally have been.

Just for kicks, I asked your question to Gemini: "Ektaal is classified under Tisra Jati. This classification is based on the rhythmic pattern and the division of beats within the cycle.
Tisra Jati is characterized by a rhythmic cycle that can be divided into groups of 3 and 2 beats. Ektaal, with its 12-beat cycle divided into groups of 2+3+2+3, fits this pattern."

Ah, why do I not trust Gemini? haha. I mean, why would it say a 12-beat rhythm cycle can be divided into 2+3+2+3?

Math does not seem to be Gemini's strong suit. Although 23+23 would be accurate. Addition ... Multiplication ... what's the difference really?

I have an answer prepared, almost. I need one clarification I hope you can provide: are Eka tala and Ektaal the same thing?

No, Aaron. Eka-taala is Carnatic, Ektaal is Hindustani. They may have some historical connection, but I'm still trying to find it.

Well, I tried. :-\ I'm still putting my money on tisra jaati.

@Aaron Not necessarily related to the topic, but if I were to divide 12 into groups of 2 and 3, I'd do 2+2+3+2+3 (or some rotation thereof), which is a Euclidean rhythm.
